# ReactJS: Make Material UI Dialog Box Pop Up Full Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dialog

When I click on a button, I have a [Material UI dialog box](https://v4.mui.com/components/dialogs/) pop up successfully (yay!). Now I just want it to be full screen rather than only a small portion of the screen. I am trying to follow along in the [Material UI API for the dialog box](https://v4.mui.com/api/dialog/#dialog-api), but my box is not appearing full screen. Is there some sort of disconnect that I am missing here? Thanks a lot in advance (sorry if this is a noob question).

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import PhotoScrolling from './PhotoScrolling';

/* const useStyles = makeStyles({
    imageSlider: {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      color: 'black',
      width: 400,
    },
  }); */

export default function FormDialog() {
    // const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
            Open form dialog
        </Button>
        <Dialog 
            open={open} 
            onClose={handleClose} 
            aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title"
            fullScreen={true}
            fullWidth={true}
            >Section Title</DialogTitle>
                <PhotoScrolling></PhotoScrolling>
            <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                Close
            </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling fullscreen={fullscreen} inside `<Dialog fullscreen={fullscreen}/>` it will work fine.

You are making mistake by calling it inside `<DialogTitle/>`.

Hope this will work.

```
return 
   (
    <div>
    <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
    </Button>
    <Dialog 
        open={open} 
        onClose={handleClose} 
        fullScreen={true}//Here you need to add the function
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >

        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title"
        fullWidth={true}
         >Section Title</DialogTitle>
            
        <PhotoScrolling></PhotoScrolling>
        <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Close
        </Button>
        </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
    </div>
    )
```